# Why am I getting method overriding error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, method-hiding

THis is my superclass:

```
class Superclass {

       int a=89;

       final  static void m( int p){
            System.out.println("Inside superclass");
       }   

       static void n(){
            system.out.print("superclass");
       }

}
```

This is my subclass::

```
 class Subclass extends Superclass {

        int a=90;

        static  void m( int p){
             System.out.println("Inside subclass");
        }

        static void n(){
             system.out.print("subclass");  
        }
  }
```

Main class:

```
   class main {
        public  static void main(String[] args) {
            Subclass.m(89);
           new Subclass().n();
        }
   }
```

the problem is that i cannot understand why Javac is giving me overriding error in static method..an P.S plzz elaborate that all rules for overriding are also valid for hiding. like

> The new method definition must have the same method signature (i.e.,
>   method name and parameters) and the same return type. Whether
>   parameters in the overriding method should be final is at the
>   discretion of the subclass  method's signature does not encompass the
>   final modifier of parameters, only their types and order.

The new

> method definition cannot narrow the accessibility of the method, but
>   it can widen it  The new method definition can only specify all or
>   none, or a subset of the exception classes (including their
>   subclasses) specified in the throws clause of the overridden method in
>   the superclass

**my error is:**
run:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - m(int) in javaapplication3.Subclass cannot override
>   m(int) in javaapplication3.Superclass   overridden method is
>   static,final  at javaapplication3.Subclass.m(JavaApplication3.java:18)
>     at javaapplication3.min.main(JavaApplication3.java:25) Java Result: 1

also i want to ask if static members called from classname to resolve whicch version of method is executed when method is hidden by subclass extending the superclass 
what if i make anonymous object and then call method then how the compiler determines which version of method should be called.
in above code in main class i type this: new Subclass().n();

how does the compiler know subclass version of method should be called even if i am not providing the type of reference variable

Comment: You cannot override final methods. Final declares methods to not be overriden.

Comment: @bzzzrd is right, how do you suppose to override a final/sealed member? it doesn't make sense!!

Answer (score 5):

From the [JLS 8.4.3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3):

> A method can be declared final to prevent subclasses from overriding or hiding it.

Static methods with the same signature from the parent class are [hidden](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) when called from an instance of the subclass.  However, you can't override/hide [final methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html).
The keyword `final` will disable the method from being hidden. So they cannot be hidden and an attempt to do so will result in a compiler error. There is a nice explanation on this on [Javaranch](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/OverridingVsHiding).

Answer (score 2):

What you are observing here is in accordance with [JLS 8.4.3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3) which states that:

> **It is a compile-time error to attempt to override or hide a final
>   method.**

You are trying to override `final static void m` method in subclass , which is not permitted by Java compiler.

Comment: he is trying to override or hide?

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel He is trying to overhide.

Comment: Does that concept exists? I thought static methods can't be overriden just hidden.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel Yes you are right. It is hiding . My bad that I called this concept as overhiding.. :)